# SQL how to find a specific string or character after finding the first and second string with the INSTR() function?

Tags: mysql, sql, function

I am trying to find a string with the character "e" occurring three times in my relational database. I already found a way to find a string with the character 'e' occurring twice using the following code:

```
SELECT lastname
FROM participants
WHERE INSTR(lastname, 'e') AND INSTR(SUBSTRING(lastname,INSTR(lastname, 'e') + 1), 'e');
```

How do I find a string with the character "e" occurring three times in a string?

Comment: `WHERE length(customerName) = length(replace(customerName,'e',''))+3`  change 3 to 4 if you need to find 4 etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT LENGTH('efooefooe') - LENGTH(REPLACE('efooefooe', 'e', ''));
```

Gives 3.

So:

```
SELECT lastname
FROM participants
WHERE LENGTH(lastname) - LENGTH(REPLACE(lastname, 'e', '')) = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace 'e' with a blank string and compare the length of the original string to the string with 'e' replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Use `like`.  For three or more appearances:

```
where lastname like '%e%e%e%'
```

For exactly three appearances:

```
where lastname like '%e%e%e%' and lastname not like '%e%e%e%e%'
```

If you have a case-insensitive collation and want to avoid finding `'E'`, then convert to a case sensitive collation.

Comment: `like` is case insensitive in mysql so this would match 'E' too.